# How to load plugins in an app build with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have got a python app which loads plugins as modules at runtime.

```
module = importlib.import_module("plugins." + modulename)
```

Now I want to build an executable using pyinstaller, but at runtime I get the a ModuleNotFoundError. How can I handle dynamic module loading. Just to be clear, these plugins/modules are not available during the build process.

Edit: added some sample code
interface.py

```
class Plugin:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def doSomethingUsefull(self, a, b):
        pass
```

main.py

```
import inspect
import pathlib
import os
from interface import Plugin
from importlib import import_module

def loadPlugins():
        plugins_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "plugins")
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(plugins_dir):
            for file in files:
                modulename, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
                if ext == ".py":
                    module = import_module("plugins." + modulename)
                    for name, klass in inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isclass):
                        if klass.__module__ == "plugins." + modulename:
                            instance = klass()
                            if isinstance(instance, Plugin):
                                print("Plugin Call:", instance.doSomethingUsefull(3, 5))
            break # not to list __pycache__ etc

loadPlugins()
```

plugins/test.py

```
from interface import Plugin

class TestPlugin(Plugin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def doSomethingUsefull(self, a, b):
        return a * b
```

I am getting this error after creating an executable:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
    loadPlugins()
  File "main.py", line 15, in loadPlugins
    module = import_module("plugins." + modulename)
  File "importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plugins'
[3451] Failed to execute script main
```

Here is also a tree:

```
.
├── interface.py
├── main
├── main.py
├── main.spec
└── plugins
    └── test.py
```

When I run the app with `python3 main.py` I am getting this output:

```
Plugin Call: 15
```

Comment: If you want to import your modules dynamically you need to create a standard procedure for it. E.g you can create a `module` directory next to your app and ask the user to put the plugins inside it, Is this what you want?
Also if you need a more robust answer you should add a minimal working example of your app.

Comment: No. The loading of plugins is already working fine. Only when I am building an executable with pyinstaller my procedure is not working anymore.

Comment: When you freeze your app all your modules would merge into a single executable and you can't change anything inside it. So as I said you need to create a **pattern for your external plugins**.

Comment: I don't want to change anything inside. I want to load an external plugin which is not know on freezing time. Just a simple python file to be interpreted.

Comment: So you want to feed the plugins on build time but it may change am I right?

Comment: No. The plugins will be executed on runtime. They are non existend at build time. As I wrote: Just to be clear, these plugins/modules are not available during the build process.

Comment: So As I said you need to load them manually inside your code from a directory, or create a GUI and get the module path from User. I think there is no other way for that.

Comment: I have added sample code so that you may get the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily I have found a solution.
I forgot to mention that I have used the - - onefile option for pyinstaller where the app is looking for modules in sys._MEIPASS instead of os getcwd().
When I don't use - - onefile everything works properly.